# Opening spartacus in smartedit giving Uncaught Error in browser console

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

When trying to open Spartacus in smartedit, I am getting the below error:-
Uncaught Error: 
        Allowed whitelist characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, period, or *
        The wildcard * can be used to represent a prefixed domain, Good example: *.domain.com:80
        but not a suffix or port, Bad examples: subdomain.*.com subdomain.domain.com:*.
        Every whitelisting must contain a specific port.

```
at webApplicationInjector.js:15
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Function.t.convertWhitelistingToRegexp (webApplicationInjector.js:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (webApplicationInjector.js:4)
at n (webApplicationInjector.js:4)
at webApplicationInjector.js:4
at webApplicationInjector.js:4
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `data-smartedit-allow-origin`. It needs to have a port. `localhost:80` will work; `localhost` will not work. *Adjust the port accordingly. If it's running on HTTPS, then it needs to be 443 or some other custom value.*

You may also need to adjust the domain. e.g. `stackoverflow.com:443`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the issue is not in localhost, its on my cloud, there we use a domain name and I have given that domain name for data-smartedit-allow-origin.

Comment: @Amal I updated the answer. You need to adjust both the domain and the port. Let me know if it works. Then, maybe you can upvote and accept the answer if it worked. :)

Comment: it is still not working. I am using a domain url which is being setup in my cloud. So not using any port.

Comment: @Amal I understand that it doesn't have any port, but you need to specify the port explicitly.  If your site is something like `https://backoffice.c39j2-walkersde1-d4-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/` , then you need to put `backoffice.c39j2-walkersde1-d4-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com:443` in `data-martedit-allow-origin`